# Sum of a group of a group: group_by summarise

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe cosisting of the columns: productnr,amount, Type (Type of product) and company. The dataframe tells me which company bought what and the amount of it.

I want to find how many products were sold of each type of product. The code I came up with stems from following logic. First I try to find total amount sold per productnr. This result I use to sum the amount of every productnr that belongs to a certain type to find total sold per type.

However like this I get impossible results. I am pretty sure my logic with grouped_by and summarise is wrong, but I can't understand why.

Every bit of help would be kindly appreciated.

**Dataframe example**

I have a dataframe structured like this:

| Productnr | Type | Amount | Company |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Apple | 29 | Company1 |
| 1 | Pear | 271 | Company2 |
| 3 | Apple | 565 | Company2 |
| 2 | Banana | 354 | Company2 |
| 2 | Pear | 984 | Company3 |
| 1 | Banana | 247 | Company3 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

**CODE**

```
Aantal_type2<-MASTERDATA%>%
  group_by(Type,Productnr)%>%
  summarise(Aantal_per_art=sum(Amount,na.rm=TRUE),
            Time=Time,Type=Type)%>%
  summarise(Aantal_per_type=sum(Aantal_per_art,na.rm=TRUE),
            Time=Time,Type=Type)%>%
  filter(!is.na(Type))
```

I used some variations of these code, but nothing gave the desired result. So I am stuck on this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to calculate the amount sold for each 'Type' ignoring things like Productnr and Company, than you can just ignore these in your grouping. So, to calculate the amount sold for each 'Type' simply group on that factor using the following code:

```
Aantal_type2 <- MASTERDATA %>%
        group_by(Type) %>%
        summarize(Aantal_per_type = sum(Amount, na.rm=TRUE)) %>% 
        filter(!is.na(Type))
```

You should then be able to create a bar plot of the amount sold using the code you already provided:

```
Aantal_type2 %>%
        ggplot(aes(x = Type,y = Aantal_per_type, na.rm = TRUE))+
        geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

Hope this helps you toward your goal.

Comment: I am sorry, overlooked this. It has to only contain integers.

Comment: Okay, I edited my post and response. If this answer works for you, please accept is the correct answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I clearly made a stupid mistake of thinking that productnr would be summed twice but that's not the case. thanks for the answer!

Comment: You were headed in the right direction with your thinking. Once you use group_by and summarize together for a little while it becomes more intuitive. Keep it up and good luck on your work!